# C# uwp application not building in release mode

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I'm trying to build my application in release mode but it's not working. Debug works fine. The error I get is:

```
STDERR: ERROR: The asynchronous operation was failed: The package could not be installed because a higher version of this package is already installed (hresult_error:80073D06)[location] = c:\buildagent\work\bfdcd5891b5bc64\resharperautomationtools\native\solution\winrt_launcher\src\utility.hpp(41)[function] = void __cdecl jbrs::wait_for_finished(const struct winrt::com_ptr<struct IAsyncInfo> &)[package name] = Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.7[uri] = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.6\tools\Runtime\x64\Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.7.appx
```

These are the windows sdks

```
 <TargetPlatformVersion Condition=" '$(TargetPlatformVersion)' == '' ">10.0.18362.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
 <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.15063.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
```

This is the uwp version

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform">
      <Version>6.2.10</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

I'm unable to figure out how to fix it and was unable to find anything else on the internet. Would appreciate it if someone could help.

**Update (Fixed it)**

I was able to fix it by downgrading uwp to 5.2.8. (Using Rider) I did it by going to the NuGet Tab and then selecting the second item in the context menu.

[image]

After that I also had to downgrade the project by clicking on the button next to the button with the red line.

[image]

Comment: If you solved your problem you should put it in the Your Answer box below; after a day or so you can accept your own answer. That will mark your question as solved in the UI, and people searching for the same problem will be shown your answer.

Comment: Thanks, added my own answer, will mark it as answered tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update (Fixed it)**

I was able to fix it by downgrading uwp to 5.2.8. (Using Rider) I did it by doing going to the NuGet Tab and then selecting the second item in the context menu.

[image]

After that I also had to downgrade the project by clicking on the button next to the button with the red line.

[image]